# c++ pass char array to function and change it

Tags: c++

I try to make a function that can change the content of a specified char array

```
void change_array(char *target)
{
    target="hi";
}

int main()
{
    char *a[2];
    change_array(a[1]);
    cout<<*(a[1]);
}
```

But then the content of a[1] stays at 0x0(void)

Comment: There are answers telling you how to pass by reference, so I'm going to raise the question of "should you be doing it this way". The answer is *almost certainly* "no, no you should not". Why are you using `char*`s, and not `std::string`s? If you don't have an immediate and pressing need for c-strings, I would suggest using `std::string`s instead.

Comment: No no,I have my own reason to use string as I am writing something like core war that need to read the char array word by word.

Comment: you could use a char** for this. but I would go for anjruu solutions use string.

Comment: @Echo: That does not really matter, you can still use a `std::string` (or maybe better for this use case `std::vector<char>`) to manage the memory for you. There are a few things wrong with those few lines of code: `a` is uninitialized *stays at 0x0* is incorrect, rather *remains with an indetermined value*. A string literal is *not* a `char*` (although for historical reasons the compiler might allow `target="hi";`, but if you attempt to modify it the behavior will be undefined and most probably crash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an argument to a function, it's normally passed by value, meaning its value is copied. If you want to change it you have to pass it by reference. The same goes for pointers, if you want to change a pointer then you need to pass it by reference as well:

```
void change_array(const char*& target) { ... }
```

Comment: ain't I passing by reference now?

Comment: @Echo If you only wanted to pass a single character by reference you could do it with a pointer. But you want to change the actual pointer, so you need to pass the whole pointer by reference. And in C++, you do it with "proper" references and not by using pointers.

Answer (score 3):

First, your function has a copy of the pointer passed to it, so there is no effect seen on the caller side. If you want to modify the function argument, pass a reference:

```
void change_array(char*& target) { ... }
//                     ^
```

Second, you cannot/should not bind a non-const pointer to a string literal. Use `const char*` instead.

```
void change_array(const char*& target) { ... }
//                ^^^^^      ^

int main()
{
    const char* a[2];
    change_array(a[1]);
    cout<<*(a[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it as a reference:

```
void change_array(char*&target)
{
    target="hi";
}
```

Otherwise, you will just change the local copy of `target`, which won't make any difference to the value outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this design instead:

```
std::string get_string()
{
    return "hi";
}

int main()
{
    std::string a[2];
    a[1] = get_string();
    std::cout<< a[1];
}
```

Salient points:

- return by value
- use std::string

Comment: My actual target is not to show the string, but to really change it for future works